# How can I change the sort order of a D3 ordinal scale?

Tags: d3.js

I have been working with Mike Bostock's [Sortable Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705), which nicely staggers the sorting of an ordinal axis.

The initial sort is done from the left (starting A, B, C…) , but the reverse is done with the same order (A, B, C…) rather than from the left. This means that the letters start moving from seemingly random positions and the eye can't follow it as easily as the first sort.

I have been trying to resolve this, but I suspect that this may be a limitation of ordinal scales: the sort order is that specified in setting the domain. The sorting element of the code is at the bottom.

```
var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked
    ? function(a, b) { return b.frequency - a.frequency; }
    : function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter); })
    .map(function(d) { return d.letter; }))
    .copy();

var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
    delay = function(d, i) { return i * 50; };

transition.selectAll(".bar")
    .delay(delay)
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d.letter); });

transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("g")
    .delay(delay);
```

The x0 scale is created as a copy of the x scale to provide a static reference point for the transition of the bars, as x is tweened during the transition. In the process, I think the x.domain is also set to the target sort order. I thought that the i values would be reset on setting a new domain, but it appears not: they persist through the change in domain order.

**How can I change the sort order so that the sort always starts with the left-most category?** I've tried (unsuccessfully) creating an artificial sort order on the "g", trying to work with multiple domains, etc. I can achieve this using a linear scale, but the ordinal scale should be a more concise and more elegant solution!

I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajlund/gfsAL/) so you can experiment with this.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly (and I'm not sure I do), you need to take the *previous* index of the element into account, not the new one: http://jsfiddle.net/gfsAL/1/

Comment: Yes, that's right. You've effectively shown me where I was going wrong: I was trying to pin an old_i to an each(d) not an each(this). Many thanks Lars - I'll credit that as an answer if you put it up as such.

Comment: Technically you could also save it with the data instead of the DOM. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start of the transition as per your specification would be determined by the order *before updating*. That is, the element with the lowest index before the update should be first. To do that, you simply need to store and reference the old index for the transition:

```
.each(function(d, i) { this.old_i = i; })
// ...
delay = function(d, i) { return this.old_i * 250; }
```

Note that you need to save the index for both the bars and the axis ticks/labels, as you are transitioning both.

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gfsAL/2/). Note that I'm also rebinding the data on update -- this is necessary to make it work when changing back to the original data, as the index doesn't change if you only change the scale.

Comment: Thank you Lars. It's a shame it's not quite as elegant (e.g. not being able to use the defined transition for both bars and axis labels), but it works and that's the main thing.